# CSS template not working with Login.aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, web

I've finished building my ASP.NET website. I downloaded many templates for the design, I applied them to the master page, and they worked fine for my pages.But "Login.aspx" and "ChangePassword.aspx" and "ChangePasswordSuccess.aspx" and "Register.aspx" which are built in with the website don't apply the templates!

They are not applying the new look only, They worked fine with the default style
Can any one help me with this, I don't understand the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: If might be helpful posting a link to the problem is possible and your question is quite vague at the moment... It could some paths that you need to change to reflect the move you made for the folders.

Comment: Hello, have you detail of your problem ?

Comment: I've checked the paths hundred times, nothing wrong :(

Comment: Check if those login-related pages are using the same master page as other pages.

Comment: They have the same master page

Answer (score 0):

try to write the path of the css file with ~ or with ../

ex:

```
href="~/Styles/Site.css"
href="../Styles/Site.css"
```